# Frequency of a response to occur

Tags: probability

Suppose I have three data sets (a control group, a group under the first medication and a group under the second medication). The data is non-parametric, groups are equally distributed and their size is small. I want to analyse the frequency of a certain response (so it is a "yes or no" type of problem; they either had the response or didn't have). What method works better to calculate the probability that this response will occur in each group?

I was told Fisher's exact test is probably the best method, but I'm not sure how I would do it. From what I've read the tables are $2 \times 2$ and I'm not sure how I would fit the control group in it. Does it even make sense to use this method? Is there a way to analyse three groups with this test? Is there any other method? I need some answers.

Help?

Comment: By 'equally distributed', do you mean that the three groups have the same number of subjects? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, same number of subjects.

Comment: The hypothetical data in my Answer have 100 subjects in each group, but the three groups need not have the the same number of subjects (as long as no group is to small to be informative).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a chi-squared test on a $2\times 3$ matrix of counts, where columns are 'Control', '1st', and '2nd' groups. Hypothetical data below.

```
y = c(21, 32, 38)
n = c(79, 68, 62)
MAT = rbind(y, n)
chisq.test(MAT)


        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 7.0351, df = 2, p-value = 0.02967
```

From the P-value, we see that the result is significant at the 5% level (also the 3% level). That is, we reject the null hypothesis that positive and negative responses are equally likely in all three groups.

If counts are very small so that you get error messages, then you could use the simulation option
of `chisq.test` (with parameter `sim=T`) or Fisher's exact test in R using 'fisher.test` which will work with a $2\times 3$ matrix (giving P-value $0.0207).$

*Addendum* per comment: Data with no Yes's in Control group.

```
y = c(0, 32, 38)
n = c(100, 68, 62)
MAT = rbind(y, n)
chisq.test(MAT)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 46.658, df = 2, p-value = 7.383e-11
```

Even though there are no Yes's in the Control group, the expected counts are all well above 5. However, maybe you should consider what it means to include the control group.

```
 chisq.test(MAT)$exp
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
y 23.33333 23.33333 23.33333
n 76.66667 76.66667 76.66667
```

Comment: I don't understand the chi-squared test very well (not a stats guy), but doesn't the chi-squared test requires that the frequency isn't too low on each cell? For example, if my control group has no response, then I'm gonna have a cell on the control group with frequency 0. Wouldn't it produce errors on the final result?

Never mind, I read your entire answer now. I'm gonna try that. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'control group has no response'? That there are no Yes's? Or that there are no responses at all? If the latter, I don't see how the control group tells you anything.// It is the _Expected_ counts in the cells that should be at least 5.

Comment: I mean when the control group gives you only 0 to 5 yes's. Does the last part of your answer solves that?

Comment: As mentioned in my addendum, it's the _expected_ counts that can't  be too small. // But Yes, if they are, then the last sentence of my first comment mentions how to take care of small expected counts (in some cases, anyhow). (This would have been a lot simpler if you had shown your actual data.)